# Bootstrap selectpicker focus event

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently using the bootstrap plugin "selectpicker", ant I am showing a searchbar using : data-live-search="true"

I am facing a little problem with this. When I navigate the form using "tab", and I arrive to my selectpicker field, two things can happen:

- I can press the down arrow, and then the searchbar will be focused, this is what I want.
- If I start to type letters instead of the down arrow, it will not focus the field, which is quite bad for user experience.

I thought to focus the searchbar as soon as the selectpicker field is focused, but I don't know how to create a focus event on a selectpicker...

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, and the event "show.bs.select" (from the selectpicker plugin spec) were the solution eventually, hope it be usefull to you as well..